# Como compartir en facebook un texto desde cualquier URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Buenos días a todos.

Tengo un Widget escrito en JAVASCRIPT, que se puede integrar en cualquier web de nuestros clientes y permite realizar acciones a través de este Widget a nuestra página.

Para aclarar un poco mas. 
Tenemos el widget JS en nuestro servidor que le llamamos origen.net y el cliente puede insertar mediante una llamada, el script en su Web que la llamaremos cliente.com con un codigo similar a este:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="origen.net/wwidget.js?id=2ZVdFF5UWM3cmVXR3IxVWZ2OHUrUVpXSkxFQ"></script>
```

Toda la ejecución del script funciona correctamente. El problema viene cuando quiero que el usuario pueda utilizar el botón COMPARTIR CON FACEBOOK definido dentro del Widget. Este botón sólo tiene que publicar un texto simple y la URL del cliente.

Facebook obliga a crear un ID de aplicación, el cual tengo hecho y obliga a definir el dominio o dominios desde donde se pueden compartir. No es posible definir dentro de Facebook todos y cada uno de los dominios donde los clientes pondrán el Widget y si comparto desde la Web del cliente, Facebook lanza este error:

> No se puede cargar la URL: El dominio de esta URL no está incluido en los dominios de la aplicación. Para poder cargar esta URL, agrega todos los dominios y subdominios de tu aplicación en el campo "Dominios de la aplicación" en la configuración de la aplicación.

He intentado crear una página en mi servidor origen.net, para que muestre la información que quiero y la comparta en facebook, pero todas las URL e informaciones que se comparten en Facebook van a nuestro servidor y quiero que vayan a la Web del cliente.

¿Conocéis alguna forma o configuración para compartir anónimamente un texto simple a Facebook, con una url del cliente y que no me de el error?

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como crear un compartir que envíe la información a Facebook sin que sea una URL a una Web (solo quiero texto y url del cliente como información adicional)?

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: ¿has consultado la documentación de desarrolladores de Facebook? Si el problema lo arroja Facebook, dudo que puedas llegar mas lejos. ¿cuántos dominios puedes agregar en la configuración del widget?

Comment: Mauricio, el tema es que no puedo estar añadiendo todos los dominios donde el cliente podrá el Widget. Es información que muchas veces no tenemos. la solución debe pasar por enviar una URL a Facebook, con lo que quiero compartir y que no tenga URL de donde Facebook deba leer los titulares, images y descripción. Simplemente enviar la info a facebook.

Comment: Pau Vidal, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta ampliando la descripción de cómo los clientes usarán tu widget. No creo estar comprendiendo muy bien. Con lo que puedo compararlo es que quieres crear un post en facebook. Si es así, [consulta la documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing) o [mira en este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdtOk8keCs4) que muestra cómo se crea una publicación usando la API de facebook. Saludos